# Peewee - Select all fields from a subquery

Tags: python, peewee

I am struggling with an issue in peewee for some time. I am using multiple joins, with different subqueries, and many times I want to select all the fields from the subquery in the next subquery, something like:

```py
query1 = MyModel.select(MyModel.name, fn.AVG(MyModel.grade).alias("mean_grade")).group_by(MyModel.name)
query2 = MyModel.select(query1.c.name, query1.c.mean_grade).from_(query1).order_by(query1.c.mean_grade)
```

After the 4th subquery or so, the number of fields gets bigger and bigger, and I would like to be able to selects all the columns in one go, like this:

```py
query2 = MyModel.select(query1).from_(query1).order_by(query1.c.mean_grade)
```

But I cannot figure out the best way to do this.

Also, I feel like the "peewee.Select" function might be better to use than the hack "MyModel.select(..).from_(...)", but I can't figure out out to use it properly either.

Thanks !